# Can a Taylor Series converge at a point when the remainder term cannot be bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Taylor's Theorem (in the version I'm most familiar with) states that for a function $f$ which is $n+1$ times continuously differentiable on an open neighborhood containing the segment $L$ between $a$ and $a+h$, then
$$f(a+h) = f(a) + f'(a)h + \frac{1}{2!} f''(a)h^2 + \cdots + \frac{1}{n!}f^{(n)}(a)h^n + R_n(h)$$
Where 
$$R_n(h) = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)h^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$
for some $\xi \in L$.  If we let
$$M_n = \sup_{y \in L}\left|\frac{f^{(n+1)}(y)h^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\right|$$
and let $f$ be infinitely differentiable in some open neighborhood of $L$, then $M_n \to 0$ implies that 
$$f(a+h) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)h^n}{n!} \tag{1}$$

I am wondering if there are any examples of functions $f$ for which $M_n \not\to 0$, but equation (1) still holds for some $a$ and $h \not= 0$.

Comment: You need to check the conditions for when a series converges.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I'm not sure I understand.  I know we need $R_n(h)$ to go to 0 in order to (1) to hold, but this can happen without $M_n$ going to zero (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: Functions for which the power series converges (analytic, holomorphic or entire are three different names for such functions used more or less interchangeably) are subject to some really strict behaviours, so I personally suspect that no such function exists, even though the reason for non-existense might not be as simple as just something you "missed".

Comment: I think you would be satisfied if you looked at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. A simple example is $\ln 2$ from the Taylor series for $\ln (1 + x)$. In particular,
$$ \ln (1 + x) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{n + 1}x^n}{n},$$
and the remainder term does not go to $0$ when $x = 1$. But the resulting alternating series does actually converge to $\ln 2$.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.  Maybe I'm missing something, but I compute
$$M_n = \sup_{y \in (0,1)} \left|\frac{n!(-1)^{n+2}y^{n+1}}{(1+y)^{n+1}(n+1)!}\right| = \frac{1}{(n+1)2^{n+1}}$$
which goes to zero as $n \to \infty$.